# Why does robomongo not process an immediately executing anonymous function in .robomongorc.js?

Tags: robo3t

When I put the following into .robomongorc.js:

```
function doStuff() { return "hi"; }
```

Then I can find doStuff via autocompletion and do something like

```
print(doStuff())
```

which tells me the function has loaded successfully. However, it does not work when I put the following into .robomongorc.js

```
(function(){
   function doStuff(){ return "hi"!;}
})();
```

I'm currently trying to load the underscore library (which also loads up via an immediately executing anonymous function) into robomongo and I'm thinking this is what's currently stopping me from doing so. Any ideas?

Comment: Note: For the people copy-pasting your doStuff function - you need to fix the typo(misplaced exclamation point). Otherwise loading the .robomongorc.js file fails silently.

Comment: I've fixed the above-mentioned typo

Answer (score 0):

Realised I was being stupid. The answer is because the doStuff function is hidden inside the closure created by the anonymous function. Therefore doStuff is not globally accessible.